# how to dynamically change the max value of rating in angularjs bootstrap ui

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

I just started using angularjs. I am using angularjs [bootstrap-ui](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for this project. I am rating directive and I want to change the max value. But the changes are not reflected on the rating directive

```
<rating ng-model="rate" max="max"></rating>
<a href="#" ng-click="change(10)">Change Max</a>
```

I start with `$scope.max = 5` it works. But if I change the max using a function like so.

```
$scope.change = function(value) {
   $scope.max = value;
}
```

This is not reflected in the directive.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

It does work - I tried it out in the below plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/trD0zNYW8Var8eEWrKPj?p=preview

```
<rating ng-model="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null"></rating>
    <a href="#" ng-click="change(8)">Change Maxim</a>
```

Can you console.log and see the output?